# Style of OpenFileDialog when using Syncfusion in WPF

Tags: wpf, openfiledialog, syncfusion

I'm using Syncfusion to change the style of my WPF application to the Office 2007 Blue style. But the `OpenFileDialog` shows in the default style of my OS (XP) and there doesn't seem to be any way to change its style.

Is there a way to make the style of the dialog consistent with the rest of the application? (Apart from creating my own version of `OpenFileDialog` from scratch.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the OpenFilDialog is an OS dialog.  You can't (afik) change it.  If you want to customize it, you are pretty much going to have to build your own.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible! Normally, themes should not be applied to any of the CommonDialogs such as OpenDialog. If your requirement of applying theme has more priority you need to create a custom OpenFileDialog using their's Chromeless Window.